# Ordering by updated_at per group

Tags: laravel, group-by, sql-order-by, query-builder

I have the following simple query to attempt to get the last updated row per `module`:

```
    $distincts = SerialNumber::where('company_id', Auth::user()->active_company_id)
        ->groupBy('module')
        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

This doesn't work the way I want it to. Each row in the `module` group will not be ordered by `updated_at` (which is a datetime stamp).

How can I use `orderBy` for each row in a group? Thanks for reading!

The following works, but is a very bad solution:

```
    $distincts = array();

    $modules = SerialNumber::select('module')
        ->where('company_id', Auth::user()->active_company_id)
        ->groupBy('module')
        ->pluck('module');

    foreach ($modules as $mod) {
        $se = SerialNumber::where('company_id', Auth::user()->active_company_id)
            ->where('module', $mod)
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->first();

        $distincts[] = $se;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a subquery:

```
$query = SerialNumber::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->getQuery();

$distincts = DB::table(DB::raw("(". $query->toSql() . ") as subQuery"))
    ->where('company_id', Auth::user()->active_company_id)
    ->groupBy('module')
    ->get();
```

This makes that you get only the latest records in group.

Comment: Getting a sql error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from `serial_numbers` order by `updated_at` desc from `serial_numbers` ' at line 1 (SQL: select select * from `serial_numbers` order by `updated_at` desc from `serial_numbers` where `company_id` = 1 group by `module`)

Comment: After some further testing, this query doesn't seem to work. For example, in a `contact_report` module my last `updated_at` row has an `index_number` of 20. The query returns 16, but I don't see why. Here is a dump of all results: http://hastebin.com/lasazejuxe.coffee

Comment: in this particullar example it seems that you need to add: `->groupBy('module', 'index_number'), because it been hidden whil;e grouping and was thikin first. Try it.